# How to create objects and add them to scenes using a script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scene and one object, I want to write a script which will create multiples that object with different `transform.position` The object is defined in the folder `_prefabs`.

This is what I have so far, but it isn't working.

```
void (int count) 
{
    while(count--)
    {
        var x = someFunctionToCreateObject();
        x.transform.position = someFunction();
        scene.add(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to google it.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/784642/is-it-possible-to-use-script-to-create-objects-in.html

```
GameObject go = new GameObject("objectName");
```

So you just create it and it gets added to the scene but the location and other things are your responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a ref to your prefab and instantiate at random positions;

```
public GameObject yourPrefabRef;

public void CreateObjects(int objectCount)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < objectCount; count++)
    {
       GameObject newObject = Instantiate (yourPrefabRef);
       newObject.transform.position = someFunction();
    }
}
```